# Javascript HTML How to create textbox with multi user (icon and text)

Tags: javascript, textbox

Currently, I need toimplement an html with javascript like as

[image]

When we input text in this textbox, it will show an autocomplete list. then we choice one of them. And we will show the icon and name of user.
I tried many ways but cannot.

So does anyone have any ideas? 
Thanks so much

Comment: Please show us your code for what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

[jQuery Token Input Plugin](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

[jQuery Token Input Plugin on Git Hub](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput)

Comment: Hi Vanga. currently we have an issue. That I want to show the autocomplete at cursor bellow. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: May be I can help you if I can see the current implementation. Is it possible to see that? Please let me know.